# Namespaced route naming conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

If I have this route in my config:

```
get '/reports/stats_by_date', to: 'reports#stats_by_date'
```

I can access that route with the symbol :stats_by_date and, oddly, not with :reports_stats_by_date.  If I add a route with a conflicting name like this:

```
get '/reports/stats_by_date', to: 'reports#stats_by_date'
get '/charts/stats_by_date', to: 'charts#stats_by_date'
```

What symbols do I use to access both of those routes now?

Comment: You can execute `get :stats_by_date` and Rails will know what you mean.  Oddly, Rails can't figure out `get :reports_stats_by_date` even though that's what it lists in the rake routes list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get '/reports/stats_by_date', to: 'reports#stats_by_date', as: xyz
get '/charts/stats_by_date', to: 'charts#stats_by_date', as: :abc
```

now you can access first one with `:xyz` and second one with `:abc`

Comment: Ah!  Yet another Rails caveat.